# How to prove something with an inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Given $y,z \in\Bbb Z$ and $x \in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, I have to prove that, for a value of $x, y = z$ for $y$ and all $z$, given that $x<y<x+1$ and $x<z<x+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x < z< x+1$ and $ x< y <x+1$ so $ -x > -y >-x-1$

$-1 < z -y < 1$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication

So $z-y$ is integer between $-1$ and $1$ and so $z-y=0 $ which implies that

$$ z=y $$